# ReactJS: State is not changing on calling setLoading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when addItems() function is called, I changed the loading state to true. but it always remains false. what I am missing here?

```
const Persons = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    addItems();
  }, []);

  let [position, setPosition] = useState(
    (props && props.match && props.match.params.placeholder) || 0
  );

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const numOfItem = 4;

  const addItems = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const items = [...data];

    for (let i = 0; i < numOfItem; i++) {
      const newItem = getData[position];
      // if no item is found than go out from that loop
      if (!newItem) break;
      position++;
      items.push(newItem);
    }

    setData(items);
    setPosition(position);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data.map(p => (
        <Person person={p} />
      ))}

      <button onClick={addItems}>Quick Load More {numOfItem} items</button>
   </>
  );
};
```

in devtools, I see loading state is always remains false.

Comment: Setting state is async. State changes are batched, so the state changing code in `addItems` does not work at all like you expect it to. Let `loading` start out as `true`, then set it to false after the items are loaded.

Comment: I need to show a spinner when loading is true

Comment: like this `{!!loading && <p>LOADING>>>>>></p>}
      {data.map(p => (
        <Person person={p} />
      ))}`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to start the loading state as `true` and after set all the items change the loading state to false.